# How does onPageChangeListener() know for which page the code is meant for?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 3 tabs which I've implemented using fragments. Let's say every time I swipe to Tab2, I want the same code to be executed, that is, I want the Tab2 content to be reloaded each time. The reason behind this is that in Tab1, the user has some options by which he can change what is to be displayed in tab2. Hence each time he goes from Tab2 to Tab1, and back to Tab2...some changes in Tab2 can be expected.
    I tried putting this code into `onCreateView()` ...but it appears in my app that `onCreateView()` is only being called once at the beginning and never again. I've learnt that another way is to use `onPageClickListener` . Now heres my doubt. I've implemented a `ViewPager` class in MainActivity to create my tabs. So my `onPageListener` is also present in `MainActivity.java` and not in the `Tab2.java` class.
    So supposing I make a `textView` in `Tab2.xml` .... and I write code for it in `onPageListener` expecting it to control the `textView` in Tab2 when I swipe to Tab2. But how does the app know that this code in `onPageListener` is for Tab2?  `onPageListener` is for all tabs, so how I specify which tab this code is for?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create an `Interface` which all of the `Fragments` in your `ViewPager` implement.  Something like:

```
public interface TabSelectedListener {

    void onSelected();
}
```

Then your have each of the Fragments implement it:

```
public class TabTwoFragment extends Fragment implements TabSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // instantiate any member classes
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // inflate the view and bind any View items (TextViews, etc)
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // do any setup of your view to get it into it's initial state
    }

    @Override
    void onSelected() {

        // any code which you want to run when the Fragment is selected in the ViewPager
        // note that this is the method we created in the TabSelectedListener interface
    }
}
```

Then in your pageChangeListener you would need to get the selected Fragment from the Adapter and cast it to your Interface so you can call the method:

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        TabSelectedListener listener = (TabSelectedListener) adapter.getItem(position);
        listener.onSelected();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
});
```

This way your Activity doesn't have to know which Fragment does what.  You can also add any code you want to each Fragment which will get run when they are focussed.

Comment: So if onPageListener is not supposed to contain the actual code for the fragments, what is it's main purpose? What type of code is it supposed to contain?

Comment: You could, in reality, put any code you want in there - it's your app after all!  I would suggest though that code in listeners is kept to a minimum and be generic/abstracted.  You don't want to be editing the listener code each time you make a change to one of your Fragments.  It should just continue working regardless of the functionality of the Fragment.

Comment: so where should the main code specific to a particular fragment go? onCreateView() ? onResume()? onPageListener()?

Comment: I've added extra comments to the Fragment sample above.  The code you want executing when the Fragment is selected in the ViewPager would go in the `onSelected` method in each individual Fragment.